# proabality mass function of this Binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

A qestion goes like this "A random sample of families is taken, and for each family with three children, the number of girls out of the three children is recorded.".
how to understand this is a Binomial distribution? what is the probability mass function? (I can understand it's a Binomial distribution if the number of families with three children is record instead of recording the number of girls.)

Comment: Given this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) how would you choose $n$ and $p$ ?

Comment: I can only think this way: n is the sample size and p is the chance of a family having three children. I can't fit "the number of girls out of the three children" into the distribution

Comment: I rather think that $n$ is three and $p$ is the probability that a child is a girl.

Comment: That is clever way of thinking. thanks!